# Check if a set of numbers satisfies a triple (X, Y, Z) given the following conditions

Tags: algorithm, sorting, logic, combinatorics

So I was trying to determine an efficient algorithm to be able to determine this but no real luck. Given a set of distinct positive integers J of length 4-7 in the range 1-10^9, determine the number of triples (X, Y, Z) that are satisfied by this set if satisfaction means that all the numbers in J are any of X, Y, Z, X+Y, X+Z, Y+Z, or X+Y+Z. X, Y, Z are positive integers and are nondecreasing respectively.

I tried to engineer a brute force solution. Given the third smallest number in J is D, we can try `(D*D*D)` different triples and check if J satisfies each of them. However, the time complexity would be too high.

**Example:** (2, 2, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 7) are the triples that are satisfied by J = {4, 5, 7, 9}

Comment: *Please mention what have you done on your own.*

Comment: @AKSingh Sure, I just edited my post.